# Merge Videos and Photos with Transitions using OpenGL ES and MediaCodec

Tags: android, opengl-es, transition, android-mediacodec

I tried to find a lot of posts or tutorials about how to work with OpenGL ES 2 in Android, however, I could find the one I want. My problem is to make **a Video Slideshow out of videos and photos combination**.

I have spent so much time reading and practicing [CTS](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) of Google but still couldn't take those codes to make what I wanted. Also, I tried to look closely to a sample project called [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) which has great examples that I can learn from. As a result, I pretty much understand so many things such `MediaCodec`, `Codec`, `MediaFormat`, `MediaMuxer` `YUV/RGB`, `FrameBuffer`, `Shaders(Vertex, Fragment)`, `Surface`, `SurfaceTexture`, `Buffer`, `EGL Stuff` such as `EGLContext` and more.

Actually, I did have some knowledge about `OpenGL` and `Shader`, but I struggled to combine all those things together.

**Ideas in My Head (That doesn't work)**

- Create a decoder which takes a `Surface` to decode a video file. The decoder has the ability to `seek` to a specific point in time.
- Create a series of frames of a photo using OpenGL textures.
- Create a shader (main shader) which takes all the shaders of video and photos and then merges it together by using two textures (External Texture). The shader would take care of applying `filters` like `Saturation`, `Brightness`, `Contrast`, ... to the whole movie.
- Create a class which extends from `TextureView` and create a thread which has OpenGL context. And let the main shader render to it. (same thing as `GLSurfaceView`)
- Create another encoder which takes the main shader and encode it into a file with `MediaMuxer`.

> If you have any ideas, it would be great, I think this is one of the most difficult problems to achieve, but I think it would be easy for those who have tons of experience with it.

**Most Inspiring Projects**

- [GPUVideo](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android) by [Masayuki Suda](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/)
- [ImageToVideoConverter](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/ImageToVideoAndroid) by [Masayuki Suda](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/)
- [Mp4Composer](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android) by [Masayuki Suda](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/)
- [AndroidGPUImage](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage/) by [CyberAgent Advanced Technology Studio](https://github.com/cats-oss)
- [ImageEditor](https://github.com/CreateChance/ImageEditor) by [CreateChance](https://github.com/CreateChance) (Full-features photos to video slide show with transitions but doesn't support videos)
- [AndroidTranscoder](https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder) by [ypresto](https://github.com/ypresto)

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I ended up doing it all by myself. Check out my project: https://github.com/seanghay/studio/

Comment: Hi
thanks for repository, but it can't allow image and video both.

Comment: @Seanghay I went through your project.It was so Amazing, Appreciated your hard work.I am actually working with some video based project  , Can i use this project to create transition effect between two videos instead of images. How can i modify the project for that??.Thanks in advance..

Comment: @LinsLouis Yeah sure